# Repo sync error: description is different in .repo/manifests\.git vs .repo/manifests.git

Tags: git, repo

`repo sync` fails for my project. Tried also with `-f` and `--force-sync` options but nothing changes.

```sh
$ repo sync -j1 -f --force-sync
warning: -f/--force-broken is now the default behavior, and the options are deprecated
error: description is different in D:/proj/.repo/manifests\.git vs D:/proj/.repo/manifests.git
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\proj\.repo\repo/main.py", line 622, in <module>
    _Main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "D:\proj\.repo\repo/main.py", line 596, in _Main
    result = run()
  File "D:\proj\.repo\repo/main.py", line 589, in <lambda>
    run = lambda: repo._Run(name, gopts, argv) or 0
  File "D:\proj\.repo\repo/main.py", line 266, in _Run
    result = cmd.Execute(copts, cargs)
  File "D:\proj\.repo\repo\subcmds\sync.py", line 858, in Execute
    self._UpdateManifestProject(opt, mp, manifest_name)
  File "D:\proj\.repo\repo\subcmds\sync.py", line 789, in _UpdateManifestProject
    mp.Sync_LocalHalf(syncbuf, submodules=self.manifest.HasSubmodules)
  File "D:\proj\.repo\repo\project.py", line 1616, in Sync_LocalHalf
    self._InitWorkTree(force_sync=force_sync, submodules=submodules)
  File "D:\proj\.repo\repo\project.py", line 3062, in _InitWorkTree
    raise e
  File "D:\proj\.repo\repo\project.py", line 3054, in _InitWorkTree
    self._CheckDirReference(self.gitdir, dotgit, share_refs=True)
  File "D:\proj\.repo\repo\project.py", line 2946, in _CheckDirReference
    raise GitError('--force-sync not enabled; cannot overwrite a local '
error.GitError: --force-sync not enabled; cannot overwrite a local work tree. If you're comfortable with the possibility of losing the work tree's git metadata, use `repo sync --force-sync .repo/manifests` to proceed.
```

Version of repo is:

```sh
$ repo --version
repo version v2.4.1
       (from https://gerrit.googlesource.com/git-repo)
repo launcher version 2.4
       (from C:\Users\User\bin\repo)
       (currently at 2.4.1)
repo User-Agent git-repo/2.4.1 (Win32) git/2.25.0.windows.1 Python/3.8.2
git 2.25.0.windows.1
git User-Agent git/2.25.0.windows.1 (Win32) git-repo/2.4.1
Python 3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
```

Any idea what is causing this, I couldn't find anything online on this.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post the content of your files : *.repo/manifests/default.xml* and *.repo/manifests.git/config* ?

Another way to launch the command, and to know if your config works :

`repo forall -p -c git pull`

then

`repo forall -p -c git fetch`

Comment: Thank you for your solution, I ended up using it and it looks like it works. But I have some concerns: what if the manifest changes on the remote repository? Does `repo sync` update also the local manifest? Because I'm pretty sure `repo forall -p -c git pull` doesn't. And I want to be sure that this is a proper alternative.

Comment: My answer was not a solution. It was just a way to investigate the issue you have with repo tool.  
As the 2 commands work, your git configuration is good for all projects. But you have to debug the repo manifest which could be the root issue.  
Could you post the files as required ?
To answer your question, `repo sync` update the local manifest but NOT the command `repo forall -p -c git fetch`.